# Javafx 8 Monopoly Board layout with image in center of board

Tags: user-interface, javafx-8

I am making a monopoly game using javafx 8 and I have stumbled upon a problem that has been keeping me busy for some hours. I use the following class to render the view of my gameboard:

```
public class SpelbordView extends GridPane {
    public Pane[] panes = new Pane[40];


    public SpelbordView() {
        initNodes();
        layoutNodes();
    }

    private void initNodes(){
    }

    private void layoutNodes(){
        RowConstraints rowsEdge = new RowConstraints();
        rowsEdge.setPercentHeight(14);
        RowConstraints rowsMid = new RowConstraints();
        rowsMid.setPercentHeight(8);

        ColumnConstraints colEdge = new ColumnConstraints();
        colEdge.setPercentWidth(14);

        ColumnConstraints colMid = new ColumnConstraints();
        colMid.setPercentWidth(8);

        this.getColumnConstraints().addAll(colEdge, colMid,
                colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colEdge);
        this.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowsEdge, rowsMid,
                rowsMid,rowsMid,rowsMid,rowsMid,rowsMid,rowsMid, rowsMid,rowsMid, rowsEdge);



        BorderPane image = new BorderPane();
        this.add(image,1,1,9,9);

        image.maxHeightProperty().bind(this.heightProperty().multiply(0.72));
        image.maxWidthProperty().bind(this.widthProperty().multiply(0.72));



        ImageView imageView = new ImageView("monopoly/view/beginscherm/images/mlogo.png");
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(image.widthProperty().divide(2));
        imageView.autosize();

        image.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(MonopolyGUIItems.getMonopolyRed(),null,null)));
        image.setCenter(imageView);


        GridPane.setHalignment(image, HPos.CENTER);
        GridPane.setValignment(image, VPos.CENTER);


        BorderPane.setAlignment(image, Pos.CENTER);

        this.setGridLinesVisible(true);


        image.setPrefSize(getHeight()*0.72, getWidth()*0.72);
        image.autosize();

    }


}
```

It works nearly perfect. But when I put the view on a stage something goes wrong.

when I start the application, the stage looks like this:
[image: Monopoly rendered wrong]

as you can see, the borderpane in which i put the image, is overlapping the other grids. This should not be happening. The strange thing is, when i manually resize the window just a little bit, the borderpane immediately adjusts it's dimensions to fit the center of the gridpane like below:

[image: correct monopoly 1] [image] [image]

Does anyone know what causes this? Or whatever is missing in my code. As I said, the dimensions of the borderpane are only wrong when the stage is first rendered. Whenever I manually resize the stage the borderpane in the center resizes perfectly no matter what dimensions i choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

1. Do not use a `BorderPane` to center a component; use `StackPane` for this purpose.
2. To enforce a nodes size to follow another, you need to bind max/min/pref sizes respectively.
3. Use comments to explain the rationale for choosing the seemingly magic number values you chose (8,14,9,0.72,...).
4. Please provide fully self contained and runnable examples. This makes it easier for others to help you.

Here is an improved version:

```
private void layoutNodes()
{
  final RowConstraints rowsEdge = new RowConstraints();
  rowsEdge.setPercentHeight( 14 );
  final RowConstraints rowsMid = new RowConstraints();
  rowsMid.setPercentHeight( 8 );

  final ColumnConstraints colEdge = new ColumnConstraints();
  colEdge.setPercentWidth( 14 );

  final ColumnConstraints colMid = new ColumnConstraints();
  colMid.setPercentWidth( 8 );

  this.getColumnConstraints().addAll( colEdge, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colMid, colEdge );
  this.getRowConstraints().addAll( rowsEdge, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsMid, rowsEdge );

  final StackPane imagePane = new StackPane();
  this.add( imagePane, 1, 1, 9, 9 );

  final DoubleBinding multipliedHeight = this.heightProperty().multiply( 0.72 );
  final DoubleBinding multipliedWidth = this.widthProperty().multiply( 0.72 );

  imagePane.maxHeightProperty().bind( multipliedHeight );
  imagePane.maxWidthProperty().bind( multipliedWidth );
  imagePane.minHeightProperty().bind( multipliedHeight );
  imagePane.minWidthProperty().bind( multipliedWidth );
  imagePane.prefHeightProperty().bind( multipliedHeight );
  imagePane.prefWidthProperty().bind( multipliedWidth );

  final ImageView imageView =
    new ImageView( "http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Wjc79oqi1y0/VHitLAU44BI/AAAAAAAAG80/0UZ9n2JmvEo/s1600/Logo%2BMonopoly.png" );
  imageView.setPreserveRatio( true );
  imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind( imagePane.widthProperty().divide( 2 ) );

  imagePane.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: red;" );
  imagePane.getChildren().add( imageView );

  this.setGridLinesVisible( true );
}
```

Full example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/flasheater/358b4a4fce069d74b419).

Comment: thanks for the solution and the advice! Is setting every variable as "final" best practice, or is it just your personal preference?